# Jquery- jtable with back batton press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

Jtable pagination is not working if I am pressing back button.
I have some 4 option in menu. First option is home and last is report. When I am clicking on report, getting a list which I am displaying by using jtable. After clicking page 1,2,3,4,10,20 new page come. But after pressing back button previous should display. For that I modified some code of jtable api.

```
    /* Performs an AJAX call to reload data of the table.
    *************************************************************************/
                _reloadTable: function (completeCallback) {
                    var self = this;
                    //Disable table since it's busy
                    self._showBusy(self.options.messages.loadingMessage, self.options.loadingAnimationDelay);
                    //Generate URL (with query string parameters) to load records
                    var loadUrl = self._createRecordLoadUrl();
                    //Load data from server
                    self._onLoadingRecords();
                    self._ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        url: loadUrl,
                        cache : false,
                        data: self._lastPostData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            var historyData = self._lastPostData;
                            historyData.url=loadUrl;
                            history.pushState(stringifyObject(self),'List',window.location.href);
                            location.hash = loadUrl;
                            self._hideBusy();
                            //Show the error message if server returns error
                            if (data.Result != 'OK') {
                                self._showError(data.Message);
                                return;
                            }
                            //Re-generate table rows
                            self._removeAllRows('reloading');
                            self._addRecordsToTable(data.Records);
                            self._onRecordsLoaded(data);
                            //Call complete callback
                            if (completeCallback) {
                                completeCallback();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            self._hideBusy(); 
                            self._showError(self.options.messages.serverCommunicationError);
                        }
                    });
                },
```

And added one more method

```
window.onhashchange = function() {       
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(eval("(" + history.state + ")"));
        if(history.state!=null){
        var self = JSON.parse(history.state);
            alert(self._createRecordLoadUrl());
            alert(self.state._lastPostData);
            self._reloadTable(completeCallback);
        }
    }
```

I am not able to call these method because self is not jtable object.
Please provide better solution.